# Confusing 行く【いく】<to go> and 行う【おこなう】<to do>

Tags: readings, collocations

Sometimes I have trouble deciding whether to read 行く【いく】 or 行う【おこなう】 since both have the same て-form, 行って

such as in this sentence

筆者【ひっしゃ】がときどき出勤前【しゅっきんまえ】にモーニングを食【た】べに行【い】っていた店【みせ】だ

*It was a place where this author sometimes had the breakfast special before going to work.*

https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/column/chottomae/20210421-OYT8T50057

(The reading above was generated by both j-talk.com and jisho.org)

Is it 行く【いく】 because it is associated with 食【た】べに (like in English, ***go*** to eat)
or is it 行う【おこなう】 because one is *performing the action* of eating?

Which is correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

いく is the correct one in this case. The reason is as you said, because it's associated with 食べに.

おこなう is a very formal expression that has various meanings when translated into English (such as to do, to conduct, to have, to make etc). You almost never hear おこなう in everyday **casual** conversation.

However, when it comes to reading, it's true, sometimes difficult to tell which way to read it at first glance.

I would say the keys are

- Pay attention to the particle before 行く/行う.
- Get some hints from the context.

#### The below are some example sentences where you can distinguish between いく and おこなう by the particle.

> 調査**に**行った。（〜に いく）
>
> I went to investigate.

> 調査**を**行った。（〜を おこなう）
>
> I did some research.

> 友だちは今、実験**に**行っています。（〜に いく）
>
> My friend is going to an experiment at the moment.

> 教授は今、実験**を**行っています。（〜を おこなう）
>
> The professor is conducting an experiment now.

#### The below are some example sentences where you can distinguish between いく and おこなう in context.

> 彼の指示どおりに行ったので、プレゼンテーションは大成功だった。（おこなった）
>
> I followed his instructions, so the presentation was a great success.

> 彼の指示どおりに行ったので、全然迷わなかった。（いった）
>
> I went (there) according to his instructions, so I didn't get lost at all.